# Почему coutn() возвращает 1 вместо 0?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Вот столкнулся с такой проблемой.
У меня есть объект `Product` со множеством полей. В этом объекте есть поле `photos` которое хранит в себе сериализованный массив фотографий т.е. массив ссылок на эти самые фото. Максимум можно хранить 5 фотографий.

Перед обновлением продукта, я считаю кол-во уже загруженных фотографий, что бы сообщить юзеру о количестве свободного места. Например продукт содержит 3 фотки, соответственно если он попытается загрузить 4, то ему в ответ что свободного места на 2 фотографии. Все ок, работает.

Для получения кол-ва фотографий я делаю следующее, пытаюсь из сериализованной строки получить массив и подсчитать кол-во элементов

```
$currentProductPhotos = count((array)unserialize($product->photos));
```

Проблема в следующем. Если например продукт не имеет фотографий, соответственно получается 5 свободных мест, но код выше возвращает мне 1, откуда эта единица берется ума не приложу) Но 4 фотографии грузятся без проблем, а вот 5 уже никак

При этом попытка продампить возвращает `null`

```
dd($product->photos)
$currentProductPhotos = count((array)unserialize($product->photos));
```

Answer (score 0):

`unserialize(null)` - возвращает пустую строку

`(array)ПустаяСтрока` - возвращает массив с одним элементом, у которого значение пустая строка

Это всё можно было бы увидеть разбив код на более мелкие части или воспользоваться **[Отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)**

Comment: В отладке было бы написано что unserialize(null) возвращает пустую строку, а (array)ПустаяСтрока возвращает массив с одним элементом, у которого значение пустая строка?) А так спасибо что объяснили, не сталкивался с подобным раньше)

Comment: "В отладке было бы написано что unserialize(null) возвращает пустую строку, а (array)ПустаяСтрока возвращает массив с одним элементом, у которого значение пустая строка?) "  ---- да..Там для каждой операции показаны значения......... если мало - то можно было в watch смотреть заранее созданные выражения